# Query criteria for time and date field individually past midnight

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am currently trying to create query update that runs across 8 hours shift. The query was successful but it got stuck at the past midnight part.
I have 3 shifts:
Shift 1: 7:30am to 4:30pm
shift 2: 4.30pm to 11:30pm
shift 3: 11:30pm to 7:30am

Query criteria for shift 3 that i have attempted:

Date:-----------------------Time:

Date()----------------------Between #11:30:00 PM# And #11:59:59 PM#

Date()+1-------------------Between #12:00:00 AM# And #7:29:59 AM#

Results: it will only work for today [date()] and when it date() reach tomorrow, it will reset to next next day.

shift 1 and shift 2 was successful however the query did not run successfully for shift 3. Both date and time are separated in the table using =date() and =time(). May i know how should i set up the criteria for shift 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *and/or*:

```sql
Shift 1: Where [TimeField] >= #07:30# And [TimeField] < #16:30#
Shift 2: Where [TimeField] >= #16:30# And [TimeField] < #23:30#
Shift 3: Where [TimeField] >= #23:30# Or  [TimeField] < #07:30#
```

To filter on a date:

```sql
Select * 
From YourTable
Where [TimeField] >= #07:30# And [TimeField] < #16:30# And [DateField] = [SelectDate]

' For the other shifts:

Where [TimeField] >= #16:30# And [TimeField] < #23:30#And [DateField] = [SelectDate]

Where ([TimeField] >= #23:30# And [DateField] = [SelectDate]) Or  ([TimeField] < #07:30# And [DateField] = DateAdd("d", 1, [SelectDate]))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. May i know where do i put this statement and what about the date when it pass 12 midnight?

Comment: Those are the WHERE clause for your query. Just add a filter for the date field if you need that.

Comment: The problem i face now is that the next day after 7:30:00am is a new shifts but the shift 3 will now be today's date before 7:30:00am + today's date after 11:30:00pm